# How do recruitment agencies work?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

How do recruiters agencies work, particularly in Australia? How much they charge the employer for a contract position? Is it better for a job seeker to apply for a specific opening by a recruiter or directly from the remuneration standpoint?

Comment: I guess each recruiting agency is different and works differently. Also, each one may charge differently. Furthermore, if it is better to seek for an opening either way is strongly opinion and circumstance based (some offers are just accessible via a recruiter, and you won't find out about it if doing it independently)

Comment: Job seeker doesn't pay for the commission, so you're ok.

Answer (score 2):

The exact details vary but typically, recruitment agencies are paid on a commission basis. For permanent roles this is often a percentage of the starting salary of the candidate while for contract roles it is an on-going fee applied each billing period of the contractor as long as the placement lasts. In all cases, the fee is paid by the employer.

Some will work on a flat fee structure where the employer pays a predetermined fixed amount upon a successful hire but (at least in the UK) this seems to be quite rare.

In rare cases, when there is no recruiter involved employers will pass some measure of the "savings" on to the candidate but in my experience this isn't especially common. A savvy candidate can sometimes use knowledge of this "savings" to negotiate a better salary, which can be an extra motivation to to the idea of dealing directly with employers.

The flip-side is that some companies will *only* recruit through agencies, either because they like the convenience of having unsuitable candidates filtered out or because of contractual exclusivity arrangements they have already agreed. This means that  avoiding recruitment agencies entirely *will* narrow your options, but if you have the option for a particular vacancy to choose between applying directly with the company or to applying through a recruiter there is generally little benefit to you as the candidate in making use of the agency.

It's worth noting that there *is* another category of recruitment agency, where the employee pays a fixed fee to a recruiter and the recruiter finds them a job. These constructions are very rare however, so when a recruitment agency approaches you offering their services, you shouldn't assume they work with such a fee. Indeed I would be **very** wary of any agency that asked for the candidate to pay a fee - especially if this was an upfront fee as this would be a major red flag that such an agency was a scam or unethical at least.

Answer (score -6):

I can give one example I recently had (in Sydney/Australia): I was on a day rate of $500 a day.  Having built a good rapport with the client and the client having an absolutely incompetent project manager I happened to see how much the client was paying for me: $830 a day. Not to mention he was also charging me for sick days/public holidays etc which I wasn't getting paid at all for.  Needless to say the recruitment agent was not happy (with the client) when I mentioned this.  Currently I am on a contract with two recruitment agencies in the middle (one here and one overseas).  I'd imagine what I am getting paid is vastly less than what the client is paying them.  In short, recruiters in Australia (Sydney at least) are pretty much like leeches, wherever possible avoid them if you can.

Comment: PS: Not very nice to get negative votes without feedback.  I was only trying to shed a bit of light on OP's question with my experience.

Comment: My down-vote was because your anecdote makes quite a broad sweeping attack on the whole Sydney / Australia recruitment industry. Per your post, your bad experiences seem to be with a very small segment of the market, temporary and contract agencies. Your post didn't sound fair to the rest, to me. It's not personal. They do sound like leeches. T

Comment: @TalbotClifton I see on your profile that you're a headhunter yourself, I understand why you downvoted.  No problemo.

Comment: +1 to @solarflare Agreed Sydney recruitments are bad. Very good answer.

Comment: While there is useful info in this answer for the most part it just reads as a rant I'm afraid.